# Django query - create record will not return ID

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am experiencing some weird behavior and not too sure why, I am currently able to do this without issue in another view.

**Here's the issue:**
I am creating and saving a new record into the database, but after save it will not give me an ID for the new record just NULL, even though the record IS BEING inserted into the DB without error.

My Code:

```
    r = KsProjectRewards()
    r.project_id = project_id
    r.reward_description_short = desc_short
    r.reward_description_long = desc_long
    r.limit_max = limit
    r.international_info = international
    r.is_active = active
    r.save()

    r.id  # <!-- THIS RETURNS NULL
```

**Here is my model**

```
class KsProjectRewards(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    project_id = models.IntegerField()
    reward_description_short = models.CharField(max_length=75L, blank=True)
    reward_description_long = models.CharField(max_length=500L, blank=True)
    num_backers = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    limit_count = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    limit_max = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    limit_met = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    delivery_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    international_info = models.CharField(max_length=200L, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField()
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ks_project_rewards'
```

Comment: Does r.pk also return NULL?

Comment: Yea tried that as well, also null

Comment: I know this is hacky, but what happens if you do `r = r.save()` and then `r.pk` ?

Comment: Anything you aren't telling us?  Are you overriding your model's `save` method, or do you have any `post_save` or `pre_save` signal handlers attached to it?

Comment: Can you show the model definition? Sounds to me like you've manually defined the `id` field but not made it an AutoField.

Comment: @dgel: not extending default save() behavior and no post/pre actions at all in the app

Comment: @karthikr: got this error ---- AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'",) is not JSON serializable

Comment: Try to delete this line from your model: id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True).

Comment: Yes that worked..... Why? lol Am I not supposed to define the ID field in Django models?

Comment: @Jingo: Do you want to formally submit an answer so I can give you the credit for it since you were the first with the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to remove the following line from your model:

```
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

Django takes care for your auto incremented field.

Answer (score 3):

You should just let django [automatically create the `id` primary key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) by removing the following line from you models:

```
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

Alternatively, if you want to explicitly define it, it will need to be an [`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField) if you want it to auto increment:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```